# How to include foreach loop containing both HTML & PHP code in PHPmailer body?

Tags: php, html, foreach, phpmailer

I just built a shopping cart in PHP/SQL and when the client places an order I want to send him an email with his order info. The issues I am having is how to include the product list within the email as a table. I tried to use a `foreach` loop containing **both HTML and PHP** but it resulted in an *HTTP error 500* when I tried to 'test drive' the template in my browser.

Here is what my code looks like :

```
    <?php 
 $body = "<h1>We're glad to see you $firstName!</h1> <br /><br />
    <p>
    Here is a recap of your next trip:<br /><br />

    You arrive on the <strong>$arrival</strong> and leave on the <strong>$departure</strong>.<br /><br />

    What you ordered:<br />
    </p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>"; //everything fine until here

    foreach($cartItems as $item) {
     $body .= "<tr><td><a href=\"#\">" . echo $item["name"]; . "</a></td>
     <td><div>" . echo $item["qty"]; . "</div></td>
     <td><span>" . echo "€".$item["subtotal"]; . "</span></td></tr>";
    } //foreach end

    $body .= "</tbody>
    </table>";

    echo $body; 
?>
```

I know the `$item["#"]` variables are working fine because when I try to `echo` them independently with a `foreach` loop it works. The problem comes when I try to somehow concatenate PHP (i.e. `echo $item["name"]`) within HTML within the `$body` variable.

N.B. This code is the one I use to test if it works on my browser. Ultimately the `$body` variable will be the content of `$mail->MsgHTML($body)`.

Thank you for your help! :)

PS: this is my first post on this website, please tell me if I can improve my question!

Comment: You don't echo within a string variable. Remove the echo and it should work. eg. ```$body .= "<tr><td><a href=\"#\">" . $item["name"] . "</a></td>
     <td><div>" . $item["qty"] . "</div></td>
     <td><span>€".$item["subtotal"] . "</span></td></tr>";```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 foreach($cartItems as $item) {
     $body .= "<tr><td><a href=\"#\">" . $item["name"] . "</a></td>
     <td><div>" . $item["qty"] . "</div></td>
     <td><span>" . "€".$item["subtotal"] . "</span></td></tr>";
    }
```

remove echo from foreach

Comment: might want to remove the semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the variable and then add to that same variable using the foreach

```
<?php     <?php
$body = "<h1>We're glad to see you $firstName!</h1> <br /><br />
<p>
  Here is a recap of your next trip:<br /><br />
  You arrive on the <strong>$arrival</strong> and leave on the     <strong>$departure</strong>.<br /><br />
  What you ordered:<br />
</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
";

foreach($cartItems as $item) {
    $body .= "<tr><td><a href=\"#\">" . $item["name"] . "</a></td>
     <td><div>" . $item["qty"] . "</div></td>
     <td><span>€". $item["subtotal"] . "</span></td></tr>";
}
$body .= "</tbody>";
$body .= "</table>";
echo $body;
?>
```

#### Improving your code

It is clearer to just use HTML and to do only the foreach in PHP.

```
<h1>We're glad to see you $firstName!</h1><br /><br />
<p>
  Here is a recap of your next trip:<br /><br />
  You arrive on the <strong>$arrival</strong> and leave on the <strong>$departure</strong>.<br /><br />
  What you ordered:<br />
</p>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";
    <?php foreach($cartItems as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#"><?= $item["name"]; ?></a></td>
            <td><div><?= $item["qty"]; ?></div></td>
            <td><span>€ <?= $item["subtotal"]; ?></span></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think this makes it more difficult to implement it in PHPmailer

Comment: That is why I gave you two options. One in case you need it in your variable.. The other if it is required to be outputted to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
     $body = "<h1>We're glad to see you $firstName!</h1> <br /><br />
    <p>
    Here is a recap of your next trip:<br /><br />

    You arrive on the <strong>$arrival</strong> and leave on the    <strong>$departure</strong>.<br /><br />

    What you ordered:<br />
    </p>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Product</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>"; //everything fine until here

    foreach($cartItems as $item) {
     $body .= "<tr><td><a href=''>" .$item["name"]. "</a></td>
     <td><div>" .$item["qty"]. "</div></td>
     <td><span>€".$item["subtotal"]. "</span></td></tr>";
    } //foreach end

    $body .= "</tbody>
    </table>";

    echo $body; 
?>
```